# How to continuously run a python script until an output is printed?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a python program to continuously run until a certain aws log is registered and printed. It is supposed to:

1. Run indefinitely even if no events happen
2. List whatever events occurs (in my case a log stating that the task is finished)
3. Stop running

the python command looks like this: `python3 watch_logs.py <log-source> --start=15:00:00`

The logs are working fine, and the python script can print them out between certain time frames as long as they already exist. The program works by taking a continuously running task which prints events to the log file, and the python script should filter out events I am looking for and print them.

But, when I run the script, it wont print the event even if I can see the log entry appear in the file. If i kill the process and run it again using the same timestamp, it will find the log entry and end the script like it should.

the code is fairly short:

```py
logs = get_log_events(
                log_group=log_group,
                start_time=start_time,
                end_time=end_time
            )
while True:
    for event in logs:
        print(event['message'].rstrip())
        sys.exit("Task complete")
```

Any insight why this is happening would help a lot. I am fairly new to python

Comment: What exactly is `logs` in that code? This example is not complete.

Comment: If your code ever would reach the section shown, there could be 3 possible actions: 1. logs is an empty collection or iterator: infinite loop due to `while True:` - 2. logs is a collection with just one element: something would be printed, program would terminate. - 3. logs is a generator function that did not yet generate anything: your program would wait until something is generated. - it looks like the first case is true, and logs is just an empty collection.

Comment: `logs` refers to a connection to an aws logging service. It vomits out thousands of events every minute. The code is built to connect to it, filter what I need, and print out the filtered items. I added the snippet that defines this. It might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the variable `logs` is old when the file is updated. You need to update this variable. For example if you were to use `logs = myfile.read()` at start of your script, the value in the `logs` variable would be a snapshot of that file at that time.

Comment: Thanks. this comment helped lead me to the answer! I put the variable that defines the logs into the loop as well, so that was being defined at each cycle. I'll update my post

Answer (score 0):

Try storing `event['message'].rstrip()` in a variable and checking with an if statement if it corresponds to the log you want to find

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read the file each time through the loop, you should have a look at pygtail (https://pypi.org/project/pygtail/).

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking the problem. I put the log variable inside the loop so it was being defined at each cycle

```
while True:
    logs = get_log_events(
        log_group=log_group,
        start_time=start_time,
        end_time=end_time
        )
        for event in logs:
            print(event['message'].rstrip())
            sys.exit("Task complete")
```